# htaccess is not working - simple rewrite Rule is doing nothing on my site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know these rewrite rules questions are all over StackOverflow - and I've read all of them. I've tested my htaccess code on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it comes back as working. 
But on my site it doesn't work.

Here's the code(currently on the site under the /new/ folder):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /new


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Here's the site: 
http://strattonindustrial.com/new/property/page

I want the **/page/** to redirect to **/page.php** in the background, but show the /page/ in the URL, but it gives me a 404 page, so no redirecting is happening. I'm basically trying to remove the ".php" from the file name and make it SEO friendly.

Additionally, I've called Godaddy and checked to make sure mod_rewrite is loaded and turned on. They can't find anything on their end that isn't working.
So it must be something with my code, but FOR THE LIFE OF ME I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /new

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Comment: so this almost there. It removes the ".php" but it doesn't redirect the page, so it's still going to a 404 page.

Comment: This is fully tested and working code on my web server. You need to check your setup why this is not working for you. May be another rule or another .htaccess?

Comment: I tried getting rid of 'Options +FollowSymLinks' and 'RewriteBase /new' but those didn't change anything. I do have this in a htaccess folder above this one: '<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>', so I erased that .htaccess file completely, but still not working. Does the internal rewrite work with folders?

Comment: or, even better, how do I see what the internal rewrite is rewriting the page to?

Comment: You can actually enable RewriteLog via `httpd.conf` and debug this.

Comment: Is there another way to debug it? Since I can't edit that (on shared hosting)

Comment: I uploaded it, but it may take a few minutes to reload??? It had a lag time earlier.

Comment: updated, but not showing any difference. Also tried removing the /new/ on the last line, adding a /new/property/ on the last line as well. Nothing.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava for all your help, by the way! So, what's happening in the last two lines is: Check if this file exists with a ".php" on it. If it does, then get everything before the forward slash and put in a variable (? not sure, on this one), and then everything after the slash in another variable. Then, redirect that to "/new/PAGENAME.php. Is that what's going on?

Comment: Your analysis is quite right, yes that is exactly happening here with that code.

Comment: I edited my answer 1 last time. See if this works for you. (All these answers have been fully tested and working code on my web server)

Comment: no dice. Everyone says the code is working - even when I find it on other StackOverflow questions, so for the life of me I can't figure out why it won't work on my websites.

Comment: So sorry I can't help you further because its difficult to guess what's going on inside your web-server.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it!!!! From this answer on StackOverflow (last answer): [godaddy mod_rewrite not working on subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569400/godaddy-mod-rewrite-not-working-on-subfolder)

Apparently, with godaddy (maybe others) you have to add:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

To the top of the .htaccess page to get it to work. Now it works like a charm.